# ToString("ddd") does not work for DayofWeek abbreviated to 3 characters

Tags: c#, dayofweek

I am trying to simply get the 3 letter acronym for the day of the week.

> Monday = MON
>   Tuesday = TUE
>   and so on.

I tried this but I get an error.

```
string wsDoW = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString("ddd");
```

The only way around it for me, is this...

```
string wsDoW = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper().Substring(0,3);
```

The error is ...

> Format String can be only "G", "g", "X", "x", "F", "f", "D" or "d".

What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `DayOfWeek` portion and your [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dddSpecifier) will work just fine.

```
string wsDoW = DateTime.Today.ToString("ddd");
```

This is due to the difference in the `ToString()` implementation between `System.DateTime` and `System.DayOfWeek`.

The `ToString` implementation in the `DateTime` class ends up [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformat.cs,da095f353f2ade5d), where it's testing for far more format specifiers.

The `ToString` implementation being called on `DayOfWeek` is in the `Enum` class, where it only checks for a [few format specifiers](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,e02a1db31e011144), and throws an exception if it isn't one of those.

Comment: ah, sorry. i didnt mean to suggest it wasnt an instance method. for some reason, i was thinking we are trying to get to the Date portion of the DateTime instance unnecessarily.